# C# and Google Sheets: Offline Mode

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, offline-mode

[Connect to Google Spreadsheet from .Net core, using Google Sheets APIs Sheets V4](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/03/google-spreadsheets-and-net-core.html)

From the link above, i've been able to connect my c# app with google sheets. For this to work, it is required an internet conection (an exception is thrown if not).

Since "Backup and Sync from Google" app for windows is installed in my computer, the offline edit mode is available for the spreadsheets synced by the app.

Does anyone know some way to take advantage of the offline mode feature in c#? So if there's no internet available i can still update my sheet?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offline editing is a feature with in the application.   You would have to code your own application to store the data and send it to Google using the API once you are online again.